# Проблема с регулярным выражением разных строк

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Честно говоря, не додумал как правильно назвать заголовок, но объясню всё подробно тут.

Есть две переменные:

```
pkill = '.*? (\w+):(\w+)'
revent = '.*? (\w+):(\w+):(\w+)'
```

Обе переменные берут данные, ища строки через `re.search` в файле `log.txt`.

Пример строки:

```
player:attacker
player:item:count

[16:04:SS]: Player:Ruby:10 # revent  - игрок получил 10 рубинов;
[16:04:SS]: Player1:Player0 # pkill - игрок0 убил игрока1;
```

---

Также у меня есть бот Discord, который постоянно проверяет файл на наличие этих строк.
Когда я для теста вписываю эти строки и сохраняю файл я ожидаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а выходит совсем другое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется лишняя строка: `:crossed_swords: Игрок Ruby убил игрока Player`

Comment: Она не лишняя. она соответствует обоим вашим шаблонам. поэтому отображается и как pkill и как revent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас регулярное выражение `pkill` находит тот же текст (его начальную часть), что и выражение `revent`.

Измените регулярное выражение в `pkill` на

```
pkill = r'.*? (\w+):(\w+)\b(?!:)'
```

См. [пример его работы](https://regex101.com/r/DaNnNW/1).

`\b(?!:)` проверяет наличие границы слова и отсутствие двоеточия сразу после слова после первого двоеточия. Также обратите внимание на префикс `r'...'`, если его не использовать, придётся удвоить символ обратной косой черты, `pkill = '.*? (\\w+):(\\w+)\\b(?!:)'` (`pkill = '.*? (\w+):(\w+)\\b(?!:)'` тоже сработает).

Comment: Я думал будет сложнее :) Спасибо!